# Why is my screen getting corner radius when button is clicked?

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't know why but some phones are getting corner radius in it's screen when I click a button. There isn't any configuration for that. I think this is because a special feature from the phone but not my code.

This are the corners I have mentioned.
[image: Black corners]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.